# how to aling text 2lines

Tags: html, css

I want to align text by 2 rows like

[image: this]

My text-align doesn't work

[image: mine]

```css
.find-icons__icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="find-icons">
  <div class="find-icons__icon">
    <i class="fas fa-qrcode fa-2x"></i><span>QR code</span>
  </div>
  <div class="find-icons__icon">
    <i class="far fa-address-book fa-2x"></i><span>Add by contacts</span>
  </div>
  <div class="find-icons__icon">
    <i class="fas fa-fingerprint fa-2x"></i><span>Add by ID</span>
  </div>
  <div class="find-icons__icon">
    <i class="far fa-envelope fa-2x"></i><span>Invite</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

you need to see  Add by Contacts

Comment: Add a `br` element ---> `<span>Add by <br/> contacts</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<br>` to wrap it on next line

```
<span>Add by <br> contacts</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

One Method using `<br>` tag.

Second method using

```
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align: center;
```

this style to `span` tag

```css
.find-icons__icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}
.find-icons__icon span{
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="find-icons">
  <div class="find-icons__icon">
    <i class="fas fa-qrcode fa-2x"></i><span>QR code</span>
  </div>
  <div class="find-icons__icon">
    <i class="far fa-address-book fa-2x"></i><span>Add by 
    contacts</span>
  </div>
  <div class="find-icons__icon">
    <i class="fas fa-fingerprint fa-2x"></i><span>Add by ID</span>
  </div>
  <div class="find-icons__icon">
    <i class="far fa-envelope fa-2x"></i><span>Invite</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please Check @Dean97K